# Visual Studio 2010 WPF Addin Doesn't Show Tab Name Correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I've created an addin for visual studio 2010 in WPF. Everything looks good except that when docked, the tab name disappears. See below for screenshot.

[image: Addin Screenshot]

I found something on the MSDN forums stating the following

> 1. Get corresponding IVsWindowFrame for mWindow using IVsUIShell.GetToolWindowEnum().
> 2. Call IVsWindowFrame.SetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_Caption, "my caption");

I've tried doing this but I can't get the IDE to recognize the method GetService in which to find the IVsUIShell. After that it gets worse.

Does anybody understand this instruction and if so, could you help me get there. It seems like I'm missing a reference, but everything else looks normal.

Thanks in Advance, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Here's the code I ended up using -

```
            // Get the service provider on the object
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.ServiceProvider(this._applicationObject as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider);

            // Get the shell service
            var vsUIShell = (IVsUIShell)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsUIShell));
            Guid slotGuid = new Guid(guidString);

            // Find the associated window frame on this toolwindow
            IVsWindowFrame wndFrame;
            vsUIShell.FindToolWindow((uint)__VSFINDTOOLWIN.FTW_fFrameOnly, ref slotGuid, out wndFrame);

            // Set the text on the window tab name
            wndFrame.SetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_Caption, "Upgraded Task List");
```

It gets the service provider from the visual studio instance. Then you can get the toolwindow frame with the GUID of the tool window. Finally, set the text on the tool window tab with the final line.

Hope that makes sense. It took me a long time to figure this out.